# Is there a way to track badwords in variable in input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to track badwords like english badwords

and i don't want to use:

```
if intext.find('badword') != -1:
   print("That's a badword")
```

because it is lengthy and i also don't want to include

the badword in the code directly

what i tried

```
#stored the badwords in a variable in a list
a = ['badword1','badword2']
b = input("Enter word")
if b.find(a) != -1:
   print("Bad word")
```

But that doesn't work!
Can anyone help?

Thanx in advance

Comment: google `Aho-Corasick automaton`,may be this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah there's a way to do it.

Code:

```py
import re
import base64 as b64

def base64(m,st):
    if int(m) == 0:
        st = st.encode('ascii')
        st = b64.b64encode(st)
        st = st.decode('ascii')
        return st
    elif int(m) == 1:
        st = st.encode('ascii')
        st = b64.b64decode(st)
        st = st.decode('ascii')
        return st
    else:
        return -1

#PUTTING BADWORDS
BADWORDS = re.compile(base64(1,"d3RmfGZ1Y2t8YXNzaG9sZXxma3xmY2t8ZnVrfGZ1Y3x3dGZrfHh4eHxzZXh5fGFzc3xzaGl0fHNleHxzc3h8c3h8c3hlfGZraW5nfGZrbmd8c3h5fHN4dXxzeGU="))

a = input("enter a word: ")

bad = BADWORDS.search(a)
if str(type(bad)) == "<class 'NoneType'>":
    print("The word you typed is: " + a)
else:
    print("That's a badword")
```

Comment: I get error:st = b64.b64decode(st)
NameError: name 'b64' is not defined

Comment: Oh wait i am updating answer ;)

Comment: OMG that's working how did you add badwords there?

Comment: It works based on:
re.compile()
and the badwords are encoded in base64 form which are decoded during the program execution ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find any bad word in a text, you can use a RegEx which matches any bad word from your bad words list.

The RegEx should be build as follow :

- special characters in the bad words must be escaped with `re.escape`,
- to match words only (and not inside long phrases), you need to delimit each bad word by a starting and a ending `\b`. You also need to use `^` to match at the beginning of the text and `$` to match at the end
- the `re.IGNORE` flag is useful if you want to ignore case

Here is an way to do that:

```py
import re

bad_words = ['badword1', 'badword2']


def has_badwords(text):
    escaped = map(re.escape, bad_words)
    regex = r'(?:\b|^)(' + '|'.join(escaped) + r')(?:\b|$)'
    return re.search(regex, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)


assert has_badwords('badword1')
assert has_badwords('badword2')
assert has_badwords('This text has a BadWord1!')
assert not has_badwords('foobadword1')
assert not has_badwords('badword1bar')
```

> don't want to include the bad words in the code directly

If you don’t want to include your bad words in the source code you can store them in an external file.

If you want to “hide” them, you can use an environment variable to store the file path.

**Note :** storing base64-encoded string in source code doesn’t mean it is hidden. One can easily decode it.

Comment: That's actually complex i don't understand
but the code given by pear was also from 
import re